# Pixlr API, POST not working anymore

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco, pixlr

I'm using the Pixlr API in Umbraco and the save functionality stopped working in the editor.

When the save button is clicked it will say: "working please wait..." and it doesn't do anything.

- When using POST, it **will** **not** go into the SavePixlr.aspx.cs
  (when the code did work I would get the image back not in an URL see: Pixlr API)
- when I use GET it **will** get into the SavePixlr.aspx.cs.
  (when I use GET I will get the URL back of the saved image)
  but I really want to have it to work like it used to.

The whole code is here: https://damp.codeplex.com/releases/view/121209
(*Only the pixlr part in DigibizAdvancedMediaPicker*)
Pixlr API: http://pixlr.com/developer/api/
I'm working on a localhost.
I have the crossdomain.xml and it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--This crossdomain file is used for Pixlr support in the Digibiz Advanced Media Picker.-->
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-access-from domain="*" />
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="true"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

I found more people with the same problem here:
http://support.pixlr.com/pixlr/topics/pixlr_api_not_saving_changes
and here:
http://support.pixlr.com/pixlr/products/pixlr_pixlr_api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all Umbraco DAMP users, a while ago I had to change the code for the Pixlr plugin to work. You can find it here: https://damp.codeplex.com/

This is the change I made, if you want to know the changes: https://damp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/MCollard/FixSavePixlr/changeset/4180f1d1d8e3
https://damp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/4180f1d1d8e3

Comment with the fork: Attempt to fix an issue with pixlr. Images wouldn't save, so I changed the POST method to GET. The Get method will return an URL instead of an image so the save part had to be changed. It is possible to save as PNG or JPEG.